# mysql - GROUP_CONCAT rows into a string

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have a following result set:

```
req_id |  p_id  | ai_result  |  hash | sku
1      |  4     | Match      |  XAN  | HOW
1      |  4     | Match      |  HXN  | HOW
1      |  4     | Non Match  |  123  | HOW
```

I need to have the following output

```
sku  | matched  |  non_matched
HOW  | XAN, HXN |  123
```

Here's as far as I could get:

```
SELECT sku, GROUP_CONCAT(hash) AS hash
FROM `sku_match` 
GROUP BY req_id, p_id
```

How can I distinguish rows based on `ai_result` column and put them separately.
Something like `GROUP_CONCAT(hash) AS matched, GROUP_CONCAT(hash) AS non_matched`?

Comment: you can try subquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    sku,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ai_result = 'Match' THEN hash END) AS matched,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ai_result = 'Non Match' THEN hash END) AS non_matched
FROM sku_match
GROUP BY
    sku;
```

[image]

### Demo